# SUTime custom date parsing

Tags: stanford-nlp

Need to parse a sentence like "Bob was born on Jan fifteen nineteen seventy nine."  and extract the date.  How do I create a new rule to handle the date expression?

If I use "Bob was born on Jan fifteenth nineteen seventy nine." the parser extracts the correct date 01/15/1979.  Simply changing "fifteenth" to "fifteen" leads to incorrect parsing.

```
val input = "Bob was born on Jan fifteenth nineteen seventy nine."
    val document = new CoreDocument(input)
    val props = new Properties()
    val annotators_ner = "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner"
    props.setProperty("annotators", annotators_ner)
    val pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props)

    pipeline.annotate(document)
    val writer = new StringWriter

    pipeline.jsonPrint(document.annotation(), writer);
    val json = writer.toString()


    println(json)
```

The json excerpt below shows correct entity mentions.

```
    "entitymentions": [
    {
      "docTokenBegin": 0,
      "docTokenEnd": 1,
      "tokenBegin": 0,
      "tokenEnd": 1,
      "text": "Bob",
      "characterOffsetBegin": 0,
      "characterOffsetEnd": 3,
      "ner": "PERSON"
    },
    {
      "docTokenBegin": 4,
      "docTokenEnd": 9,
      "tokenBegin": 4,
      "tokenEnd": 9,
      "text": "Jan fifteenth nineteen seventy nine",
      "characterOffsetBegin": 16,
      "characterOffsetEnd": 51,
      "ner": "DATE",
      "normalizedNER": "1979-01-15",
      "timex": {
        "tid": "t1",
        "type": "DATE",
        "value": "1979-01-15"
      }
    }
  ]
```

Changing the input as follows.

```
val input = "Bob was born on Jan fifteen nineteen seventy nine."
```

Leads to the following output for entity mentions.

```
"entitymentions": [
    {
      "docTokenBegin": 0,
      "docTokenEnd": 1,
      "tokenBegin": 0,
      "tokenEnd": 1,
      "text": "Bob",
      "characterOffsetBegin": 0,
      "characterOffsetEnd": 3,
      "ner": "PERSON"
    },
    {
      "docTokenBegin": 4,
      "docTokenEnd": 7,
      "tokenBegin": 4,
      "tokenEnd": 7,
      "text": "Jan fifteen nineteen",
      "characterOffsetBegin": 16,
      "characterOffsetEnd": 36,
      "ner": "DATE",
      "normalizedNER": "1519-01",
      "timex": {
        "tid": "t1",
        "type": "DATE",
        "value": "1519-01"
      }
    },
    {
      "docTokenBegin": 7,
      "docTokenEnd": 9,
      "tokenBegin": 7,
      "tokenEnd": 9,
      "text": "seventy nine",
      "characterOffsetBegin": 37,
      "characterOffsetEnd": 49,
      "ner": "NUMBER",
      "normalizedNER": "79.0"
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is complicated because I think the rules are recognizing "Jan fifteen nineteen" as January 1519.  One thing you could try is adding some post-processing rules if you find a common pattern such as "DATE" followed by "NUMBER" is actually a written out "DATE".  But you could imagine scenarios such as "In Jan Fifteen Nineteen Seventy Nine people visited".

There is a full write up about how to add TokensRegex rules to the `ner` pipeline here: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/ner.html

and info on writing tokensregex rules here: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/tokensregex.html

Comment: Could you please provide an example rule for this specific scenario.  That would give me a head start on how to craft additional rules.